# Chartjs not displaying data from a dynamic stored variable

Tags: chart.js

I am having issue in representing two datasets on my chartjs chart when both of my data is from a stored variable. When both of my data {**inbound** & **outbound**} is from a stored(and unique) variable, It shows two line graph but having similar data with the **inbound** data list inheriting the **outbound** data list. The inbound and outbound data list are two separate data and should be shown as two unique datasets on the chart.

My code is this

```
var inbound = InboundSmsCountList;
var outbound = OutboundSmsCountList;
var ff = MonthDaysList;
var combined_arraysx = [InboundSmsCountList,OutboundSmsCountList];

var max2 = combined_arraysx.reduce(function(final, current) {
    for (var i = 0; i < final.length; ++i) {
      if (current[i] > final[i]) {
        final[i] = current[i];
      }
    }
    return final;
  });
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, max2);
console.log(maxValue);

var ctx6 = document.getElementById('chartBar6').getContext('2d');
var gradient1x = ctx6.createLinearGradient(0, 350, 0, 0);
gradient1x.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(241, 0, 117,0)');
gradient1x.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(241, 0, 567,.5)');
var gradient2x = ctx6.createLinearGradient(0, 280, 0, 0);
gradient2x.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(86, 87, 255,0)');
gradient2x.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(34, 45, 255,.5)');
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ff,//['May-01', 'May-02', 'May-03', 'May-04', 'May-05', 'May-06', 'May-07', 'May-08', 'May-09', 'May-10', 'May-11', 'May-12', 'May-13', 'May-14', 'May-15', 'May-16', 'May-17', 'May-18', 'May-19', 'May-20', 'May-21', 'May-22', 'May-23', 'May-24', 'May-25', 'May-26', 'May-27', 'May-28', 'May-29', 'May-30', 'May-31'],
        datasets: [{
        label: 'Outbound',
        data: outbound,//[1, 2, 0, 0, 84, 0, 10, 16, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 71, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        borderColor: '#00cccc',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: gradient2x,
    },{
        label: 'Inbound',
        data: inbound,//[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        borderColor: '#00cccc',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: gradient1x,
    }]
      },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position:"top",
          labels: {
            display: true
          }
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          //stacked: true,
          barPercentage: 0.5,
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true,
            fontSize: 11
          },
          gridLines: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: true
          },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            //stacked: true,
          ticks: {
              fontSize: 10,
              color: '#97a3b9',
              min: 0,
              max: maxValue
          },
          gridLines: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: true
          },
        }]
      }
    }
};
new Chart(ctx6, config );
```

[when both data is from stored variable - see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScvH2.png)

```
data: {
        labels: ff,//['May-01', 'May-02', 'May-03', 'May-04', 'May-05', 'May-06', 'May-07', 'May-08', 'May-09', 'May-10', 'May-11', 'May-12', 'May-13', 'May-14', 'May-15', 'May-16', 'May-17', 'May-18', 'May-19', 'May-20', 'May-21', 'May-22', 'May-23', 'May-24', 'May-25', 'May-26', 'May-27', 'May-28', 'May-29', 'May-30', 'May-31'],
        datasets: [{
        label: 'Outbound',
        data: outbound,
        borderColor: '#00cccc',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: gradient2x,
    },{
        label: 'Inbound',
        data: inbound,
        borderColor: '#00cccc',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: gradient1x,
    }]
      }
```

[when outbound data is a stored variable while the inbound data is raw list/array it shows correct graph-two separate datasets - see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiGGG.png)

```
data: {
        labels: ff,//['May-01', 'May-02', 'May-03', 'May-04', 'May-05', 'May-06', 'May-07', 'May-08', 'May-09', 'May-10', 'May-11', 'May-12', 'May-13', 'May-14', 'May-15', 'May-16', 'May-17', 'May-18', 'May-19', 'May-20', 'May-21', 'May-22', 'May-23', 'May-24', 'May-25', 'May-26', 'May-27', 'May-28', 'May-29', 'May-30', 'May-31'],
        datasets: [{
        label: 'Outbound',
        data: outbound,
        borderColor: '#00cccc',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: gradient2x,
    },{
        label: 'Inbound',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        borderColor: '#00cccc',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: gradient1x,
    }]
      }
```

Can someone advise how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary stuff and cannot reproduce [link](https://jsfiddle.net/matrixatp/ay0bpjq7/11/)

Comment: Thank you. It must be my other variables which are unnecessary for this part.